# Insert if not exist (in mysql via phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am in phpmyadmin and I need to paste the code there to make such thing:

if there is no records in a table with certain field equals "aaa" (for example), I need to make an insert query. If there is, then i need to make an update query.

The problem is that this field is not a primary key, so I cannot use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
    INSERT INTO
    mytable
    (   key,
        attribute
    ) 
    SELECT  1,
            'aaa'
    FROM    mytable
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  0
            FROM    mytable
            WHERE   attribute = 'aaa'
        )
    ;
```

Comment: and what about update if the row with certain field = "aaa" exists?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer maybe it will help

```
@q = Select anyCol From Table Where anyCol LIKE %aaa%
IF( @q IS NULL , Insert..... , Update....)
```

You will find IF function [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx)